# Icons in window rendered way too big. (Unity, RoboMongo)

Tags: 16.04, unity

I have a weird problem and no idea what could have caused it. I installed Robomongo on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine a few months ago and it worked just fine back then, but now I've started it for the first time in months, and suddenly there are rendering issues. Functionality-wise it still works; it's just the UI that is messed up.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Does anyone of you know how I could fix this?

I haven't experienced any issues like this in other applications.

Edit:
I just reinstalled robomongo and switched from 0.9 to 1.0. I'm still experiencing the exact same issues. I also tried to run it with sudo just to see if it makes any difference, but nope. And there is no output when I run it from the terminal.

Comment: Under: >System Settings > Display Settlings,  In the lower left of the panel, what is the value on the "Scale for menu and title bars" slider?

Comment: That didn't fix it btw.

Comment: Sounds like your display's DPI (dots per inch) may be set incorrectly. (Not an answer because I don't use Unity and don't know how you would check or change the DPI setting in that environment.)

Comment: What makes you think that? Robomongo is literally the only application in which I'm experiencing this issue. Also, as I said, changing the scaling slider didn't fix it. It has always been set to 1 and when I change it, it doesn't change the UI of robomongo (while most other applications do actually scale then).